# how to update GridView row at once in sql database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, gridview

I have DLL class to call the table

```
    public DataTable GetTemTableValue(string TableName)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sConnectionString);
        conn.Open();

        string query = "select * from  " + TableName + "";

        SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = query;

        DataTable ds = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(ds);
        conn.Close();

        return ds;
    }
```

and i am binding the table to grid view

```
    private void LoadData()
    {

        clsDataAccess objDAL = new clsDataAccess();
        DataTable DS = new DataTable();

        string objBLL = DDLTemTableList.SelectedValue.ToString();
        DS = objDAL.GetTemTableValue(objBLL);

        if (DS != null && DS.Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            lblNoRecord.Visible = false;

            foreach (DataColumn col in DS.Columns)
            {
                //Declare the bound field and allocate memory for the bound field.
                BoundField bfield = new BoundField();

                //Initalize the DataField value.
                bfield.DataField = col.ColumnName;

                //Initialize the HeaderText field value.
                bfield.HeaderText = col.ColumnName;

                //Add the newly created bound field to the GridView.
                GVDataEntry.Columns.Add(bfield);

            }


            GVDataEntry.DataSource = DS;
            GVDataEntry.DataBind();
            GVDataEntry.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            lblNoRecord.Visible = true;
            GVDataEntry.DataSource = null;
            GVDataEntry.DataBind();
            //GVDataEntry.EmptyDataText = "No recorddata found";
        }
```

so Table is loading to Grid View. every time when i change the tables in dropdownbox and press search button  columns will change dynamically so how can i update data in Grid view through using RowEditing,RowUpdating function and i need to store the date in database?